# How to use wavelink with slash command

Tags: discord, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to make a music bot with slash commands with wavelink and whenever I try to make a slash command it says

```
unsupported type annotation <class 'wavelink.tracks.YouTubeTrack'>
```

And the command

```
**async def play(self, interaction: Interaction, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    await interaction.response.send_message("playing music")
    vc = self.client.voice_clients
    if not vc:
        custom_player = ZbotPlayer
        vc: ZbotPlayer = await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect(cls=custom_player)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Bot connected")
        
    if vc.is_playing():
        vc.queue.put(item=search)
        await self.client.get_channel(interaction.channel_id).send(embed=discord.Embed(title=search.title, url=search.uri, author=interaction.user, description=f"Queued {search.title}, in {vc.channel}"))
    else:
        await vc.play(search)
        await self.client.get_channel(interaction.channel_id).send(embed=discord.Embed(title=search.title, url=search.uri, author=interaction.user, description=f"Queued {search.title}, in {vc.channel}"))
        **
```

Comment: Your type hint is not valid, replace `async def play(self, interaction: Interaction, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):` with `async def play(self, interaction: Interaction, search: str):`.

Comment: now i get ]discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'play' raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given